# Issue with adding images to button in tkinter application

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I am helping with a small project where we want to add and take items away from a store. The code is below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

####################
# Variables
eggs = 0
milk = 0
butter = 0
lemon = 0
guiSize = "800x1280"

def newItemGUI():
    main.withdraw()

    def addEgg():
        global eggs
        eggs += 1
        updateLabels()

    def menu():
        global eggs
        update(eggs)
        itemWindow.destroy()
        main.deiconify()

    def updateLabels():
        eggLabel = Label(itemWindow, text = eggs)
        eggLabel.grid(row = 3,column = 0)

    itemWindow = Toplevel()
    itemWindow.geometry(guiSize)
    itemWindow.title("Add a new item")
    itemWindow.configure(background = "#a1dbcd")

    heading = Label(itemWindow, text="Add new items", font=("Arial",20),background = "#a1dbcd")
    heading.grid(row=0, columnspan = 3)

    egg = PhotoImage(file ="images/egg.gif")
    eggButton = Button(itemWindow, image = egg, command = addEgg)
    eggButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 10)
    eggLabel = Label(itemWindow, text = eggs).grid(row = 3,column = 0)

    back = Button(itemWindow, text = "Main Menu", command = menu, width = 15)
    back.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 20)

def update(eggs):

    items.delete("1.0",END)
    items.insert(END,"Eggs \t:")
    items.insert(END,eggs)
    items.insert(END,"\n")

main=tkinter.Tk()
main.geometry(guiSize)
bgColour = "#DDA0DD"
main.configure(background = bgColour)

button1 = Button(main, text="Input new products", width = 20, height = 5, command = newItemGUI)
button1.grid(column = 1, row =2, padx = 20, pady = 20)
label2 = Label(main,text = "Items in the fridge :", font =("Arial,20"), background = bgColour)
label2.grid(row=4, columnspan = 2)
items = Text(main, width = 60, height = 10)

items.insert(END,"Eggs \t:")
items.insert(END,eggs)
items.insert(END,"\n")
items.grid(row=5, columnspan = 4)

main.mainloop()
```

[image: no image displayed]

When you click on the input new products button, this takes you to a new screen. On the screen should be a photo of an egg with a count underneath. For some reason the image of the egg is not showing and the button will not click.

If I change the `eggButton` from an image to:

```
eggButton = Button(itemWindow, text = "egg", command = addEgg)
```

[image: button working with text]

this seems to allow me to click and the variable and it increases. Any idea as to what/where we have gone wrong? I know the path is correct as I can get the button to display a picture of an egg in a `Label`.

Comment: When you run it, is there an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: No errors, works all ok, it just doesn't display the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `PhotoImage` is being stored in a variable named `egg` which is local to the `newItemGUI()` function, so it (and associated image object) are being deleted when the function returns. This is a fairly common problem, so your question is likely a duplicate of another (and may get closed).

This `PhotoImage` [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) mentions avoiding this potential issue the way shown below in the **Note** near the end.

Regardless, to prevent that from happening, you can store the value somewhere else such as in an attribute of the `Toplevel` window. I would  also recommend changing its name to something more descriptive like `egg_image`.

Here are changes to your code showing what how it could be done:

```
    itemWindow.egg_image = PhotoImage(file="images/egg.gif")
    eggButton = Button(itemWindow, image=itemWindow.egg_image, command = addEgg)
```